# Is an Address and Location SObjects or a Compound Fields?

Tags: describesobject, dynamic-apex, describefieldresult, address

I am trying to build a picklist which would display all the available SObject, and global describe returns me some strange SObject `Address`, when I try to instantiate dynamically this SObject, it fails with an error

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type
> System.Address to SObject

, which is confusing me. Is an Address a SObject or a Compound Field?
If this is System.Address compound field why then it is returned in the list of available SObjects by the global describe and describe Objects method?

```
String addressSObjectName = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Address'})[0].getName();
System.debug(addressSObjectName);
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = ((SObject)Type.forName(addressSObjectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe();
```

The similar issue happens with Location.

```
String location = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Location'})[0].getName();
System.debug(location);
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = ((SObject)Type.forName(location).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe();
```

and the error is in this case

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type
> System.Location to SObject

Answer (score 1):

Actually Address and Location are both Compound Fields (System.Address, System.Location) and a SObject (Schema.Address, Schema.Location).
These SObjects are used for Field Service Lightning.

I have missed some small note [in the bottom of the documentation page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_address.htm)

> “Address” in Salesforce can also refer to the Address compound field
> found on many standard objects. When referencing the Address object in
> your Apex code, always use Schema.Address instead of Address to
> prevent confusion with the standard Address compound field. If
> referencing both the address object and the Address field in the same
> snippet, you can differentiate between the two by using System.Address
> for the field and Schema.Address for the object.

[image]

The same note is present in the documentation of Compound Field Address
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Address.htm#apex_class_system_Address

> “Address” in Salesforce can also refer to the Address standard object.
> When referencing the Address object in your Apex code, always use
> Schema.Address instead of Address to prevent confusion with the
> standard Address compound field. If referencing both the Address
> object and the Address standard field in the same snippet, you can
> differentiate between the two by using System.Address for the field
> and Schema.Address for the object.

[image]

So to fix this error, it is possible just to add 'Schema.' prefix to the passed name of an object.

```
String addressSObjectName = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Address'})[0].getName();
System.debug(addressSObjectName);
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = ((SObject)Type.forName('Schema.' + addressSObjectName).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe();
```

The similar note in located [in the bottom of the documentation page for Location](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_location.htm)

> “Location” in Salesforce can also refer to the geolocation compound
> field found on many standard objects. When referencing the Location
> object in your Apex code, always use Schema.Location instead of
> Location to prevent confusion with the standard Location compound
> field. If referencing both the Location object and the Location field
> in the same snippet, you can differentiate between the two by using
> System.Location for the field and Schema.Location for the object.

[image]

and in [the documentation of Location Compount Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_Location.htm#apex_class_system_Location)

> “Location” in Salesforce can also refer to the Location standard
> object. When referencing the Location object in your Apex code, always
> use Schema.Location instead of Location to prevent confusion with the
> standard Location compound field. If referencing both the location
> object and the Location field in the same snippet, you can
> differentiate between the two by using System.Location for the field
> and Schema.Location for the object.

[image]

The code to fix this error will be very similar

```
String location = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Location'})[0].getName();
System.debug(location);
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = ((SObject)Type.forName('Schema.'+location).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

Performance tests exhibit that in the current release `Schema.describeSObjects` method perform three times faster than the path `((SObject)Type.forName(devName).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe()`

This means it is better to use just method `Schema.describeSObjects` which does fail without the `Schema` prefix in the name of the object.

So it is possible just to use this code to get dynamically schema describe

```
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Address'})[0];
```

or

```
DescribeSObjectResult objectDescribe = Schema.describeSObjects(new List<String>{'Location'})[0];
```

Comment: Really? I remember doing these tests several years ago and ((SObject)Type.forName(devName).newInstance()).getSObjectType().getDescribe() was giving better performance